# How to edit text files

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have a text file document with only 1 line.

The line contains: `136.36666 120.2222 11.3222`

I want to create a new text file which contains: `136 120 11`

here what I have been tried to do :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] textfiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.txt");
    foreach (string txtfile in textfiles)
    {
        string tempfile=Path.GetTempFileName();
        int line_number = 0;
        string line = null;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(txtfile))
        using(var sw=new StreamWriter(tempfile))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line_number++;
                string[] SplitNumbers = line.Split('.');
              //" im stuck here"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the `SplitNumbers` array will contain: `136,36666120,222211,3222`.

My purpose is the array will contain: `136,120,11`.

What should I do instead of `line.split`?

Comment: My answer in your other question didn't help?...

Comment: Did you try the code I put in your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28180558/2330053) question?...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to convert double numbers to integers.

Replace

```
string[] SplitNumbers = line.Split('.');
```

with

```
string[] SplitNumbers = line.Split(' ')
                            .Select(x => ((int)double.Parse(x)).ToString())
                            .ToArray();
```

This code will convert all strings to `double` numbers, then will convert them to `integers` and then back to `strings`.

Comment: I didnt undertood this operation ".Select(x => ((int)double.Parse(x)).ToString())
                            .ToArray();"  it didnt work also , whats x refers to ?